# Как правильно: «выступала на двух десятках конференцИЙ» или «конференциЯХ»?

Tags: склонение, управление

Выступала на двух десятках научных конференций.

Answer (score 1):

**Выступала на двух десятках научных конференций.**

Падежное окончание выбрано верно, так как **десяток ― это грамматическое** существительное с числовым значением, которое всегда управляет Р.п.

Сравнить: Выступала **на двадцати научных конференциях** (согласование в П.п. для грамматического числительного).

Comment: То есть в первом случае управление (всегда Р.п), а во втором - согласование (падеж меняется вместе с падежом слова *двадцать*)

Comment: Как обычно: числительное в И.п.  и В. п. управляет существительным, задавая ему Р.п., а в остальных падежах согласуется с ним: двадцать километров (управление Р.п.), нет двадцати километров, в двадцати километрах, двадцатью километрами  (согласование в Р.п., П.п. и Т.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь имеет место связь типа управление между существительными *десяток* (мн. ч. *десятки*) и *конференция* (мн. ч. *конференции*): **на десятках (чего?) конференций**.

**Выступала на двух десятках научных конференций.**